# How can i get the value of a custom xml tag created using DOMParser?

Tags: javascript, angular, xml, typescript, domparser

I want to fetch the pan details of a user. I have written the below code:

```
 parseXML(XMLAsString){
    var parser=new DOMParser()
    var result=parser.parseFromString(XMLAsString, 'text/xml');
    var panElement=result.getElementsByTagName('XYZ:PAN').item(0)
    console.log(panElement);
  }
```

I am halfway there as `panElement` returns a custom xml tag as given below:

`<XYZ:PAN>ABCDS1234N</XYZ:PAN>`

Now how do i fetch the value of the `panElement`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textContent` property should give you the text wihin the tag.

```js
function parseXML(XMLAsString) {
  var parser = new DOMParser()
  var result = parser.parseFromString(XMLAsString, 'text/xml');
  var panElement = result.getElementsByTagName('XYZ:PAN').item(0)
  console.log(panElement.textContent);  // Here textContent gives the PAN number
}

parseXML("<XYZ><XYZ:PAN>ABCDS1234N</XYZ:PAN></XYZ>")
```